# jQuery animate not taking easing on transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, easing

I have a problem while trying to make a scale animation. I have a video element as a background and have scaled it to (1,1) at beginning. I have binded the mouse move in the document to get the position and scale the video whenever the mouse moves in Y axis, it scales accordingly like zoom in and out effect. However I have been trying to implement easing option to that but it just scales without the effect. Here is my code

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var pos = (event.pageY / 4000);
    $("#bgvid").animate({ 
        transform: pos 
        }, 
        {   step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'scale('+ (1+pos) +','+ (1+pos) +')');
        },
        duration: '100',
        queue:false,
        easing:'swing'
    });
});
```

So what it does is whenever cursor enters the document and moves in Y axis, it starts to scale from 1 to (1+value) whenever I move the cursor down/up scaling the `<video>` element. But it is not taking the easing.

What I am trying to achieve is similar to this website.

http://admirhadzic.com/#/project/kamui

Workaround as suggested by @ntgCleaner

my jquery

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var pos = (event.pageY/50);
    var wid = 120+pos;
    $('#bgvid').stop().animate({ 
        width : wid+'%',
        left: -(pos/2)+'%'
    }, 400,false,'swing');
});
```

element css

```
video.fullscreen { 
          position: absolute;
          top:0;
          left: 0;
          right:0;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 120%;
          z-index:1;
        }
```

Comment: not sure exactly where your problem lies, but have you tried using `.stop()` on your animate? `$('#bgvid').stop().animate(..)`.  you may be bubbling your animation since it's on a mouse move?

Comment: @ntgCleaner, it does the same thing. what can be the other technique to do that like the website i linked to?

Comment: Do you need to use scale? Can you just make the video 100% width inside of a container that you can scale using width and height?

Comment: @ntgCleaner, that makes sense. I will give it a try.

Comment: I also suggest giving your container a transition in CSS.  This will give it an ease.  on your container put `transition:all 100ms ease-in-out;`.  This will give the animation an ease

Comment: @ntgCleaner, thank your for the idea. Appreciate it ! Thumbs up !

Comment: You got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've made a [fiddle for you here](https://jsfiddle.net/n4za53vw/).

What I've done is make a container for the thing you want to scale, then I've used CSS `width` to scale the container.  I also added a `transition` effect on the container that's being animated so the thing will ease as you want.

html

```
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    var mouseY = e.pageY;
    $('.box-container').css({"width":mouseY+"px"});
})
```

css

```
.box-container {
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    transition:all 400ms ease-out; /* NOTE THIS LINE HERE FOR EASING */
}
.box-container:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    padding-top:100%;
}
.box {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: the animation worked but how to make it zoom from middle, not from the top-left side ?

Comment: That'll require a bit of math. You'll need to animate width and left position and I'm not sure how you have the container centered in the first place. You basically have to add to width and subtract half of that amount from left position

Comment: since i have placed it position-absolute. ok minus the left position but i am giving it as a percentage in width. so half of the percent is -(left%) ??

Comment: Pretty much. Can you post your css positioning?